# Algorithm for calculating the power set

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I just discovered an algorithm for finding the power set. I googled after solutions, but found none that worked any good, so I figured out one myself. But I wonder what algorithm it is, because I cannot find it on the net or in any books. I mean, does it have a name? Compared to the algorithms I found on some sites for calculating the power set, I think mine is far better and wonder why no one uses it?

This is the algorithm:

```
R <- []
L <- [ e1, e2 ... en ]
c <- 0
function: powerSet(L, c)
  R <- R union L
  for e in L starting at c
    powerSet(L\{e}, c)
  end
  return R
end
```

And here it is implemented in Java:

```
public static void powerSet(List<String> list, int count)
{
  result.add(list);

  for(int i = count; i < list.size(); i++)
  {
    List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>(list);
    temp.remove(i);

    powerSet(temp, i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Mainly for two reasons:

1. It uses **global** variables;
2. It is recursive, although this doesn't really matter much because it's an `O(2^n)` algorithm.

Comment: +1. It also adds empty sets for each element in the original set.

Comment: I should have pointed out that I only compare my algorithm to other O(2^n) algorithms. I know it's terribly slow. I came up with the algorithm because we had assignment in school to create a brute force algorithm. But to be a brute force algorithm, I think mine i really nice.

I don't really see why it would be a problem that it uses a global variable. And in many cases you don't actually store the set in a result, but perform an action on the set instead.

ChssPly76, It only adds one empty set and that's the empty set. The result of the algorithm is the power set, nothing else.

Comment: A power set consists of 2^n elements, it follows that an algorithm must be at least `O(2^n)` unless I'm terribly wrong. @rejeep

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [Rosetta Code Power Set](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Power_Set) page.  There are a few implementations of recursive solutions there (including a Java one).  In general though, a recursive solution implies a crazily large call stack which slows things down.

Answer (score 0):

```
public final static Set<Set<Character>> powerSet(Set<Character> s){
    Set<Set<Character>> result = new HashSet<Set<Character>>();
    result.add(s);
    for (Character c:s){
        Set<Character> subSet = new HashSet<Character>(s);
        subSet.remove(c);
        result.addAll(powerSet(subSet));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: -1: For reviving a dead thread with inefficient code :-) This is Omega(n!). Not O(2^n).